# P2P Audio Broadcasting with WebRTC

Tags: audio, websocket, webrtc, p2p

I have a single source and a set of audiences listening to the audio stream. If I stream using P2P WebRTC then the naive approach would be to create `N-1` connections from the speaker. which is okay up to `N < 3`. But otherwise P2P is transmission expensive. I have outlines two approaches and trying to find out which one is best suited.

1. Have a centralised server relaying and recording the audio. (-latency +cost)
2. Instead of opening `N-1` connections from source some of the terminal nodes will act as non terminal nodes and will open `K < N-1` connections to relay and record the transmission. (+latency -cost)

I am very new to WebRTC. I am planning my http side to be with C++. If I take approach (2) I add no extra cost on serverside for audio streaming. But it is not straight forward. I surely don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists and spins well. But I don't know what is already available and what are the risks of this approach.

If I take approach (1) what relaying server should I use ? that should tightly integrate with the business logic. This part I am having hard time figuring out. With websocket I find this part easy because all are in same session and all contextual informations are accessible. But here somehow I need to map user accounts with the streams and apply business logics on them. Like for certain users I will lower the volume.

I also need to broadcast data in the same stream.

I can't let anyone (who doesn't use my application) to use my TURN servers. I need some kind of token/auth system for that. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, do not reinvent the wheel. Build a webRTC media server from scratch is hard. Luckily there a bunch of options out there to simplify the task. Take a look at:

- https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/
- http://lynckia.com/licode/
- https://www.kurento.org/

Also you will have to decide whether to send all the streams to any participant or to mix them in the server and send only one to each participant in the conference. They are called the [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) and [MCU](https://webrtcglossary.com/mcu/) approaches.

Regarding the question about how to send data over the same stream, webRTC provides a mechanism called [DataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample), intended just for that. Thanks to it, you can create an stream with different tracks: audio, video, screensharing or data.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of opening N-1 connections from source some of the terminal nodes will act as non terminal nodes and will open K < N-1 connections to relay and record the transmission. (+latency -cost)

the [broadcast demo](https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Scalable-Broadcast.html) of Muaz-Khans rtcmulticonnection demonstrates this so you don't need to reinvent that wheel. As you say it has less cost than a central server but increases latency and it depends on the use-case whether that is better than a central server.

Comment: Thats a good demo. Just saw it. But it is still in infancy. It doesn't look like there is a standard protocol for that. If someone drops in the chain then what will happen. if there is a more favourable non-terminal then how will the switching happen. or ay polling mechanism. There are so many things that can be done to make such distributed systems more efficient.

Comment: it is a long way from any webrtc demo (opensource or not) to a production system. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't let anyone (who doesn't use my application) to use my TURN servers. I need some kind of token/auth system for that. How can I do that ?

The standard way of doing this is to use time-limited credentials. The coturn server supports this out of the box and has a [very good explanation in their wiki](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver#turn-rest-api)

Its not perfect but so far there have been no major cases of abuse.

Comment: Should I use my own TURN server ? or use some service like Xirus ?